# $.getJson function with special characters in title

Tags: jquery, html, json, getjson

i'm having this problem:
I try to load data from a .json file to my site, but i'm havin problems with the special characters in the title ( Ó, Í, É , space ). I CAN ONLY CHANGE THE .HTML FILE
This is an example:

**.json:**

```
{
    "Bibliotecas": [
        {
            "BIBLIOTECA": "Biblioteca General de Navarra ",
            "DIRECCIÓN ": "Plaza de San Francisco",
            "COD. POSTAL": 31001,
            "POBLACIÓN": "Pamplona",
            "TELÉFONO": 848427797,
             .....................
```

**.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
    <head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

    <title>JSON multiple zombies
    </title> 

    <script src="HostFiles/jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">




    <script>


        $(document).ready(function() {
                 $.getJSON('json/bibliotecas.json', function(json) { 

                 $.each(json.Bibliotecas, function () {

                 $('<article class="json"></article>').append(

                 '<p> ' + this.BIBLIOTECA + '</p>'  + 
                 '<p> ' + this["DIRECCIÓN "] + '</p>' + 
                 '<p> ' + this.POBLACIÓN + '</p>' + 
                 '<p> ' + this.TELÉFONO + '</p>'  + 


                 '</br></br>'
                 ).appendTo('body');


    });          

  });

});





    </script>





</head> 
<body> 

</body>
    </html>
```

**the result:**

```
Biblioteca General de Navarra

undefined

undefined

undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [square bracket notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html):

```
$.each(json.Bibliotecas, function() {
    $('<article class="json"></article>').append(
        '<p> ' + this["BIBLIOTECA"] + '</p>'  +   
        '<p> ' + this["DIRECCIÓN"] + '</p>' + 
        '<p> ' + this["POBLACIÓN"] + '</p>' +  
        '<p> ' + this["TELÉFONO"] + '</p>'  +
        // ...
```

Comment: Hi, i tryed this and still havind the same problem, nothing changed; P.S.: i'm using <meta charset="utf-8">

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, those special characters are not valid identifiers, so you can use them to define objects and/or variables.
Therefore you cannot use them to traverse your objects using the dot syntax.

You can, however, access them using the `[key]` syntax:

```
var direction = obj["Bibliotecas"][0]["DIRECCIÓN "];
```

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QDcNn/).

Your loop would become this:

```
$.each(json["Bibliotecas"], function (index, value) {
    $('<article class="json"></article>').append(
        '<p> ' + value["BIBLIOTECA"] + '</p>'  +
        '<p> ' + value["COD. POSTAL"] + '</p>' + 
        '<p> ' + value["DIRECCIÓN "] + '</p>' + 
        '<p> ' + value["POBLACIÓN"] + '</p>' +  
        '<p> ' + value["TELÉFONO"] + '</p>' + ...
    );
});
```

---

#### Update 1

The [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method, calls the callback with two params, `function (index, value)` for arrays and `function (key, value)` in case of object maps; it also doesn't apply a different context.
Therefore we have to access the values using the callback param **and not using** `this`.
I've updated the code to reflect this.

Comment: I can only work with the .html file, i cant change nothing in the .json file. I have tryed your way. It is stil not working. Please Help. This is the whole .html: http://www.lukcian.x10.mx/json5.html

Comment: I've updated the answer, there was an error in the `$.each()` function. Also, are you sure that the `Content-Type` header is correctly set for the JSON file?